# Internationalization in spring 3.1.2 using annotation not working

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, configuration-files

I am using spring 3.1.2 MVC. 
I am trying to configure web application by annotations

Here I want to implement internationalization for that I am using **LocaleChangeInterceptor** , **ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource** ,**SessionLocaleResolver** classes.
here is my config class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc 
public class MyAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource(){
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource=new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        String[] resources= {"classpath:labels","classpath:message"};
        messageSource.setBasenames(resources);
        return messageSource;
    }

@Bean 
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor=new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("locale");
    return localeChangeInterceptor;
}

@Bean
public SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver(){
    SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver=new SessionLocaleResolver();
    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("da","DK"));
    return localeResolver;
}   

public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}

}
```

But this is not working it shows default text for

```
<spring:message code="login.user.password" text="Password" />
```

as "Password".

please help me.
where as when I do following configuration in `applicationContext.xml` it works fine.

```
 <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">


 <property name="basenames">
    <list>
        <value>classpath:message</value>
        <value>classpath:labels</value>            
    </list>
</property>     
<property name="defaultEncoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" p:paramName="locale"/>
</mvc:interceptors>


<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="da_DK" />
</bean>
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i resolved my problem , i was missing init param entry in my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.config.AppConfig
        </param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

after adding this entry my config with annotation is working fine. :)

Answer (score 3):

The bean name for messageSource has to be "messageSource", with @Configuration you have it as `resourceBundleMessageSource`. Change it to this:

```
    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource(){
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource=new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        String[] resources= {"classpath:labels","classpath:message"};
        messageSource.setBasenames(resources);
        return messageSource;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Biju, i have made change in bean name as "messageSource", and problem of default text is resolved but my interceptor is not working. that is when i click on link to change locale request is not intercepted by **LocaleChangeInterceptor** , so is there any special bean name for **LocaleChangeInterceptor** too ? please help..

Comment: No, I think what you did is right for LocaleChangeInterceptor - Can you add an @Override to addInterceptors method just to ensure that you have not made any mistakes in overriding the method.

Comment: Great, It worked! Can someone please point to documentation where is this written?